# "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got NCLOB" error when trying to save large xml using the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g

I get the following error when I try to insert new record with large xml into the oracle table with XmlType column using ADO.NET Entity Framework.

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException
            Message=ORA-06550: line 5, column 22:
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got NCLOB
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

The data type of the property mapped to this column is string.

However when I try to insert a small xml it saves it without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

On the Oracle ODAC documentation they note that there's a 2000 character limit currently with saving to the XML data type.

> An "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB" error
>   will be encountered when trying to bind a string that is equal to or
>   greater than 2,000 characters in length to an XMLType column or
>   parameter. [Bug 12630958]